# Launch VMWare virtual machine from another host

Tags: virtual-machine, multi-boot, vmware

I have a triple-booting PC with Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 and Kali Linux 2016.1.

I have installed VMWare 12.1 on Kali, which runs several VMs. Every VM's files are stored on an external HDD reachable from Win, Ubuntu, and obviously Kali.

I would like to know if I install VMWare on the other two systems, will I be able to run the same VMs smoothly without messing them up?

Answer (score 0):

In general, virtual machines are pretty portable (especially if virtual devices are configured to use auto-detect for configuration).

If your virtual machine depends on external resources (e.g. a floppy disk image, ISO image, or host-specific devices), then obviously those parts will need to be reconfigured for other hosts.

Note that when you try to power on the virtual machine on another host, VMware Workstation will notice that it was powered on from a different location than it was previously and ask you if you moved it or copied it.  In your case you probably want to use "I moved it" to preserve the VM's UUID and MAC address.